# Python I/O: How to use the wsgi.input stream from io module

Tags: python, io, wsgi

In a WSGI application we can read the row input data from the *wsgi.input* field:

```
def application(env, start_response):
        .....
        data = env['wsgi.input'].read(num_bytes)
        .....
```

However, I want to wrap the file-like object using the new *io* module:

```
import io
def application(env, start_response):
        .....
        f = io.open(env['wsgi.input'], 'rb')
        buffer = bytearray(buff_size)
        read = f.readinto(buffer)
        .....
```

The problem is that `io.open` doesn't accept these kind of file objects. Any idea on how to do that? I need to read from `env['wsgi.input']` to a buffer.

Answer (score 2):

The `io.open()` function does not accept file-object as the first parameter.

However, it accepts an integer representing the handle to an open file. so you may have some success using:

```
f = io.open(env['wsgi.input'].fileno, 'rb')
```

**Addendum:**

The io module is written for python 3, where string handling is quite different from python 2. calling `read()` on a file opened in binary mode returns a `bytes` object in python 3, but a `str` in python 2, but when wrapping a file using the `io` module and using binary mode, the io module expect `read()` to return `bytes`.

You can try fixing your original file object by making it return `bytes`:

```
def fix(file):
    # wrap 'func' to convert its return value to bytes using the specified encoding
    def wrap(func, encoding):
        def read(*args, **kwargs):
            return bytes(func(*args, **kwargs), encoding)
        return read
    file.read = wrap(file.read, 'ascii')

fix(env['wsgi.input'])
f = io.open(env['wsgi.input'].fileno, 'rb')
```

The above function wraps the `read()` method, but can be completed to wrap `readline()`. also, a small additional work is required to wrap `readlines()`...

Comment: Now it accepts the file, but it says: TypeError: read() should return bytes.

Comment: ooops, `fileno` is a function and not a property. i forgot to really call the function. code fixed now...

Comment: It basically means that read() over a wsgi file returns probably chars instead of bytes..

Comment: remove the 'b' from the mode string: using the io module in binary mode, your file should return `bytes`, but a standard python 2 implementation of a file return a `str` (which is a `unicode` object for the `io` module)

Comment: do you really need to open this stream in binary mode ?

Comment: Yes, because otherwise you end up having a _io.TextIOWrapper object that does not have the 'readinto' attribute...

Comment: @Lluis: i augmented my answer with some code that may fix your problem. tried here with a simplified test case and it seemed to work, but i cannot guarantee that it is the solution to your problem (aka. use at your own risk).

Comment: @Lluis: before you try, the `fix()` function is using a closure. if you know what a closure is, ignore this comment. if you don't, do not try simplifying the function calls, `read()` is inside `wrap()` for a specific purpose (saving the value of `func`, that's called a closure and has to be written this way...

Comment: Accessing fileno on wsgi.input like that is outside of the WSGI specification and you shouldn't do it if you want your application to be WSGI compliant.